# Change URL for proxy_pass based on header

Tags: nginx, proxypass

There are a few similar question, but they do not solve my problem.

I use nginx as a proxy for a cdn. If the browser is accepting `webp` as image format, it should be served, else the original.

It's assumed that there are always `myfilename.jpg` and `myfilename.jpg.webp` (i have a fallback that generates the images if they do not exist).

I do this mapping:

```
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    default   "";
    "~*webp"  ".webp";
}
```

And this is the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name images.cdn.de;

    error_page 403 404 = /-;

    location /- {
        proxy_pass         http://web:8808;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Original-URI       $original_uri;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        internal;
    }


    location / {

      set $original_uri $uri$is_args$args;

      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_set_header       Host 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
      proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
      proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
      proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
      proxy_buffering        off;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;

      expires 1y;

      proxy_pass https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/media/public/images/;
    }
  }
```

The idea is that if an image is there, it get's directly served from s3. If it not there (there are cropping directives within the filename) it's generated by the `web:8808` service on the fly and uploaded for subsequent calls to s3.

That work's fine.

I'd like to know how I can add the `$webp_suffix` (which defaults to an empty string) to the url passed to the s3 proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the URI if it ends in `.jpg`. You could just add a `rewrite ... break` statement to the `location /` block.

As you have a URI appended to the `proxy_pass` directive, the `rewrite ... break` will cause any URI aliasing to be bypassed. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

A clean solution might be to always rewrite the URI, rather than relying on `proxy_pass` aliasing effect:

```
location / {
    rewrite \.jpg$ /neuraum/media/public/images$uri$webp_suffix break;
    rewrite ^ /neuraum/media/public/images$uri break;
    ...
    proxy_pass https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```

Comment: I had this one similar, but it ends up of always not finding the image.

With accept webp:
`nginx_1  | 2016/09/08 08:16:01 [notice] 7#7: *13 rewritten data: "/Sample.max-170x50.jpg.webp", args: "", client: 172.17.0.1, server: images.cdn.de, request: "GET /Sample.max-170x50.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "images.cdn.de"`

Without:

`nginx_1  | 2016/09/08 08:16:25 [notice] 7#7: *16 "\.(png|jpg)" matches "/Sample.max-170x50.jpg", client: 172.17.0.1, server: images.cdn.de, request: "GET /Sample.max-170x50.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "images.cdn.de"`

It works if the line is gone (always as jpg).

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: You got an entry in my book of cool people.